# Composite DTO projections using a Constructor Expression and JPQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to select specific columns from db into a composite class DTO by giving fully qualified names.

```
 @Data
    public class Temp {
    String dName;
    Temp2 value;

    public Temp( String dName, Temp2 value) {
        this.dName = dName;
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Data
    public static class Temp2 {
        Integer day;
        public Temp2(Integer day) {
            this.day = day;
        }
    }
 }
```

> Query: SELECT new com.pojo.Temp ( t1.displayName,  new
>   com.pojo.Temp.Temp2 (t3.day))  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.bId
>   = t2.id AND LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.g_id = t2.id

```
Error: `[2018-11-06 12:02:54] [main] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.reportError -  [  ] line 1:64: unexpected token: ,
[2018-11-06 12:02:54] [main] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.reportError -  [  ] line 1:64: unexpected token: ,
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: ,
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1009)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3549)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3273)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2930)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:615)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2697)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2558)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2522)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2403)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2116)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2357)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1390)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.newExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1434)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1306)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1040)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
    `
```

I am not able to find any relevant answers for getting data into composite class dto using jpql expression. Since i am new i might be missing something.

Any kind help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting constructor expressions like this is not possible AFAIK. There's one way to do it that I know of, but it's a dirty and ugly work around. I put all the params in one constructor and then instantiated the other class objects inside the constructor.

Example:

```
    public CommentDTO(Long id, String body, LocalDateTime datePosted,
                  LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate, Long userId,
                  String login, String avatarUrl, boolean hireable) {
    this.id = id;
    this.body = body;
    this.datePosted = datePosted;
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    this.author = new UserDTO(userId, login, avatarUrl, hireable);
```

So the JPQL query would have to have all of those params.

Again, wouldn't recommend doing it this way as it becomes 100% unmaintanable. But it's the only way I've found to do it with constructor expressions.

I just refactored to using interface based projections. If you're using Spring Data JPA, it's ridiculously easy to set it up for nested projections.

Comment: thanks @abrandell. i was also avoiding to have a constructor with too much arguments. I was curious to find if it is possible to nest constructors in jpql. since it seems logical to nest constructor in this way. I don't understand what can be the reason to not support this.

Comment: Interface projections with nested entities trigger multiple queries, which can cause [performance issues](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-query-projections/#Mapping_Nested_Associations).