# Spring Data JPA - Nested DTO projection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use DTO projection to obtain my desire output.

Here are my domain models.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Thread> threads;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Post> posts;

    // Omitted Getter and Setter
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Thread {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // Omitted Getter and Setter
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "thread_id")
    private Thread thread;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // Omitted Getter and Setter
}
```

And here are my DTO record.

```
public record UserActivityDTO(
        int id,
        String alias,
        String title,
        Date joinedDate,
        Set<SimpleThreadDTO> threads,
        Set<SimplePostDTO> posts
) {}
```

And here are my query

```
    @Query(value = """
            SELECT new com.project.package.core.User.DTO.UserActivityDTO(
                u.id as id,
                u.alias as alias,
                u.title as title,
                u.joinedDate as joinedDate,
                new com.project.package.core.ThreadAndPost.SimpleThreadDTO(t.id, t.name) as threads,
                new com.project.package.core.ThreadAndPost.SimplePostDTO(p.id, p.name) as posts
            )
            FROM User u
            LEFT JOIN FETCH u.threads t
            LEFT JOIN FETCH u.posts p
            WHERE u.id = :id
            """)
    CompletableFuture<UserActivityDTO> getUserActivity(@Param("id") int id);
```

But when I started the server, I received the error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 6, column 5 [SELECT new com.myproject.mypackage.core.User.DTO.UserActivityDTO(
    u.id as id,
    u.alias as alias,
    u.title as title,
    u.joinedDate as joinedDate,
    new com.project.package.core.ThreadAndPost.SimpleThreadDTO(t.id, t.name) as threads,
    new com.project.package.core.ThreadAndPost.SimplePostDTO(p.id, p.name) as posts
)
FROM com.project.package.core.User.User u
LEFT JOIN FETCH u.threads t
LEFT JOIN FETCH u.posts p
WHERE u.id = :id
]
```

So, I knew that the JPQL didn't allowed nested DTO in query. May you please help me to obtain my expected result effectively. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composite DTO projections using a Constructor Expression and JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166982/composite-dto-projections-using-a-constructor-expression-and-jpql)